# shinymeta: how to use expandChain in modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an app with modules in which the user can create as many UI as he wants. Each UI contain one table and I would like to give the possibility to the user to see the code for each of this table separately, not in a unique chunk. Therefore, I included the part of the code with `expandChain` in my module (`module_server`).

However, `expandChain` won't detect the reactive stuff I'm calling because the name of this stuff changes since it is created in a module. Take a look at the app below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinymeta)
library(WDI)

module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton(ns("show_table"), "Show table"),
      actionButton(ns("show_code"), "Show code"),
      tableOutput(ns("table"))
    )
  )
}

module_server <- function(input, output, session){
  data <- metaReactive2({
    req(input$show_table)

    isolate(metaExpr({
      mtcars 
    }))
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  observeEvent(input$show_code, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      renderPrint({
        expandChain(data())
      })
    ))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("launch", "Launch")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveValues(value = 0)

  observeEvent(input$launch, {
    count$value <- count$value + 1
    insertUI(selector = "#launch",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = module_ui(count$value))
    callModule(module_server, count$value)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I try to show the code for the table generated, I have the error:

```
Warning: Error in : <text>:2:2: unexpected input
1: `1_data` <- mtcars
2: 1_
    ^
  133: <Anonymous>
```

Since the module renames `data()` by adding a number, `data()` is not recognized by `expandChain`.  I tried with:

```
expandChain(paste0(id, "_data()"))
```

without success (since `expandChain` does not support character).

Does anybody know how to do it?

Also asked on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/expandchain-not-working-in-modules/53198)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution given on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/expandchain-not-working-in-modules/53198/2) (see the link for some additional details):

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinymeta)
library(WDI)

module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton(ns("show_table"), "Show table"),
      actionButton(ns("show_code"), "Show code"),
      tableOutput(ns("table"))
    )
  )
}

module_server <- function(input, output, session){
  data <- metaReactive2({
    req(input$show_table)

    isolate(metaExpr({
      mtcars 
    }))
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

  observeEvent(input$show_code, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      renderPrint({
        expandChain(data())
      })
    ))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("launch", "Launch")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveValues(value = 0)

  observeEvent(input$launch, {
    count$value <- count$value + 1
    insertUI(selector = "#launch",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = module_ui(paste0("x", count$value)))
    callModule(module_server, paste0("x", count$value))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```